# Bundle Identifier name selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

Is it possible to choose the bundle identifier like   **org.appname.appname** instead of **com.mydomian.appname**? Because I am able to create bundle id(like **org.appname.appname**) and provisioning profile and also able to build. Would it be failed in appstore submission?

Comment: the Apple recommends to use the reverse domain format for avoiding any interferences between bundle ids – regarding they are unique in Apple's system. so, you are encouraged to use `org.appname.appname` because that is a kind of reverse domain format.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't fail. It just has to conform reverse domain format.

Be careful that the Bundle Id in your app, iTunes connect, iCloud are all set to the same value.

Also, the Bundle id must be unique for your app, which is why they recommend using the domain as part of it to reduce the chance of a clash with another app.

See [Configuring Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) for guidance

However, I'd still recommend following Apple's best practices, and use com.companyname.appname

Answer (score 0):

You bundle identifier just has to meet the criteria when creating your app in the iTunes Connect platform.

`You cannot use special characters such as @, &, *, ', "`

So org@appname@appname would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be invalid, but it may get used by someone else as its quits predictable, I would suggest go for the domain name structure to name your bundleID

Comment: If invalid means It would have throw the error at the time of app id creation right? Why it allowed?

Comment: yes, It allowed because its not invalid, just a bit predictable, there can be other people who's use the same way, and bundle id is supposed to be unique